# Where clause failed on three level nested include

Tags: node.js, nested, sequelize.js

I has four modelDBList： **AlarmsDB， MonitorSpotDB， MonitorGroupDB, UserDB**

these modelDB has reference as list:

```
AlarmDB.belongsTo(MonitorSpotDB);
MonitorSpotDB.belongsTo(MonitorGroupDB);
MonitorGroupDB.hasMany(MonitorSpotDB);
UserDB.belongsToMany(MonitorGroupDB, { through: MonitorGroupUserDB});
MonitorGroupDB.belongsToMany(UserDB, { through: MonitorGroupUserDB,});
```

Now I want to get alarm relative user, so I use sequelize write code like:

```
  public async getAlarms(limit: number, offset: number, whereQuery: any, whereUser: any): Promise<{ count: number, rows: Alarm[] }> {
    let alarms = await AlarmDB.findAndCount({
        limit: limit,
        offset: offset,
        order: [
            ["createdAt", "desc"],
        ],
        where: whereQuery,
        include: [
            {
                model: MonitorSpotDB, as: "monitorSpot", attributes: ["id", "name", "monitorGroupId"], required: true,
                include: [{
                    model: MonitorGroupDB, as: "monitorGroup", attributes: ["id", "name"], required: true,
                    include: [{ model: UserDB, as: "users", attributes: ["id", "name"], where: whereUser }],
                }],
            },
        ],
    });
    return alarms;
}
```

but I get null array, If I delete

```
include: [{ model: UserDB, as: "users", attributes: ["id", "name"], where: whereUser }],
```

I can get data, I don't what to cause this problem, this is run error[image]

[image]

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors